# how can I get a substring based of a character

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Like if

```
    <email>bob@smith.com</email>
```

how can I get xsl to just give me smith.com?

Comment: ive been googling around I can't believe something so simple would take so much.

Comment: What do you want to happen if there is no `@` in the input? Should it output (1) the whole input? (2) the emtpy string? OR (3) Don't care because it will never happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function **[substring-after()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-substring-after)**

> The substring-after function returns the substring of the first
>   argument string that follows the first occurrence of the second
>   argument string in the first argument string, or the empty string if
>   the first argument string does not contain the second argument string.
>   For example, substring-after("1999/04/01","/") returns 04/01, and
>   substring-after("1999/04/01","19") returns 99/04/01.

```
<xsl:template match="email">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., '@')"/>
</xsl:template>
```